# node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(404) while migration in windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm-install, bcrypt

May be this question already asked but that's not solving my issue.

I try to migrate my `Node.Js` project one system to another one system, that time application shows `bcrypt` error while `npm install`. Error is following:

[image]

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.325.0",
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "date-and-time": "^0.6.2",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "dateformat": "^3.0.2",
    "generate-password": "^1.5.1",
    "get-mac-address": "^1.0.0",
}
```

help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

> npm --build-from-source install bcrypt

or

> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

before installing the package.json.

Hope this might work.

Comment: Thank for your answer Aldo. I got this error https://ibb.co/51GjvZc

Comment: I came across the link https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions which might be useful for you, where there mentioned about this, 
for windows, try ***npm install --global --production windows-build-tools***, then ***npm install***, could you update if it is working?

Comment: thanks for your answer i tried in powershell now it is working